# In Kendo UI MVC Grid how do i add a Kendo Upload to each row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to upload a document for each row.  Any ideas on how to do this?

```
(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(col =>
      {
          col.Template(@<text>@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                                                     .Name("attachments<#= ID #>")
                                                     .Multiple(false)
                                                     .Async(async => async
                                                          .Save("Save", "Controller", new { folder = "<#= ID #>" })
                                                         .AutoUpload(true)
                                                         )
                                                     )</text>).Title("Import");
     })
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a template for a column in MVC you just set the EditorTemplateName

```
columns.Bound(e => e.myColumn).EditorTemplateName("uploadTemplate")
```

And then define the template that you want to use somewhere else on the page.

```
<script id="uploadTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("attachments")
    .....
    .ToClientTemplate()
  )
</script>
```

Comment: So this didn't seem to work.  It is only showing the bound column text.  No template.  Any ideas?  My grid is ajax style, which might be the problem.

Comment: To get it to work i created a partial view called "UploadTemplate".  And that seemed to work.  Another question is how do I get this to work on an unbound column.  i want to be able to hit the edit button and then the upload button will show up in either the same column as the edit or its own column with nothing else in it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say you need to add the .ToClientTemplate() to the Kendo if you want to include it in the same page. Added it to the answer.